# Python/Pandas: Find the Custom Business Quarter End of a datetime which takes holidays into account

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, time-series

I want to find the Business Quarter End of a datetime in python which will take care of holidays as well. These holidays may be passed as list for simplicity. I know `BQuarterEnd()` from `pandas.tseries.offsets`. As far as I know, it doesn't take holidays into account.

Example: If `2020-11-20` is passed and `2020-12-31` is a business day but a holiday as well; it should return `2020-12-30`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pandas, there are a set of [`Custom business days`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#custom-business-days) functions where you can define your own list of holidays and then the functions calculate the correct date offsets for you, taking into account the custom holiday list.

For example, we have [`CustomBusinessMonthEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessMonthEnd.html) (better documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessMonthEnd.html)).  Unfortunately, there is no corresponding *`CustomBusinessQuarterEnd`* *(`Custom Business QuarterEnd`)* function for quarter end.

However, we can still get some workaround solution, like below:

1. Define your custom holiday list, e.g. :

```
holiday_list = ['2020-12-31']
```

2. Make use of a combination of [`QuarterEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd.html) + [`CustomBusinessMonthEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessMonthEnd.html) to get the required date for *`Custom Business QuarterEnd`* skipping the holidays:

```
import pandas as pd

base_date = pd.to_datetime('2020-11-20')   # Base date

custom_business_quarter_end = (base_date 
                                   + pd.offsets.QuarterEnd(n=0) 
                                   - pd.offsets.MonthBegin() 
                                   + pd.offsets.CustomBusinessMonthEnd(holidays=holiday_list))
```

Firstly, we add your base date to the `QuarterEnd` to get the quarter end date (without considering holidays). Then, to get the *`Custom Business QuarterEnd`* skipping the holidays, we use the [`CustomBusinessMonthEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessMonthEnd.html) passing also the holiday list as parameter for it to adjust for the holidays.

For [`QuarterEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd.html), we pass the parameter `n=0` to handle the edge case where the base date is already on the Quarter End date.  We avoid `QuarterEnd` to rollover this quarter end date to the next quarter end date.  You can refer to the official doc [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#anchored-offset-semantics) to know more about how Pandas handles dates falling onto anchor dates (see the subsection starting with "For the case when n=0, ...")

We also make use of [`MonthBegin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin.html) first before calling [`CustomBusinessMonthEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessMonthEnd.html).  This is to avoid rolling over of a day **at month-end anchor** to the next month.  We need this because the `n=0` parameter does not work similarly for [`CustomBusinessMonthEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessMonthEnd.html) like how it works for [`QuarterEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd.html) to avoid rolling over. Hence,  this extra minus [`MonthBegin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin.html) is required. With the use of [`MonthBegin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin.html), we get the month begin date of the quarter-end, i.e.  `2020-12-01` first, and then get the custom business month-end date. In this way, we can avoid the result of `QuarterEnd` e.g. `2020-12-31` being rolled over to the next month end e.g. `2021-01-31` when directly calling [`CustomBusinessMonthEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessMonthEnd.html).

**Result:**

```
print(custom_business_quarter_end)

2020-12-30 00:00:00
```

Comment: this was great. Thanks.
Some edge cases fail for me using this. One, when the base date is not a business date
e.g for `2022-12-31`, it gives `2023-03-31`, but the expected is `2022-12-30`. In this case, the holidays' list is empty for simplicity. maybe QuarterEnd() instead of BQuarterEnd does the job.

Another case for which it doesn't give desired output: Suppose the given date is BQuarterEnd and is a holiday too. e.g `2020-12-31` is the base date as well as holiday. It gives `2021-03-31`.

Comment: @ParasGupta  Thanks for the thorough testing and advised the edge cases.  For the edge cases, it can be handled by we further get the month begin by `MonthBegin`  before calling `BQuarterEnd`.  This will do the same as our original use of `MonthBegin` before calling `CustomBusinessMonthEnd` to avoid unwanted rolling over at month-end anchor dates.  You can take a look and retry it.  Let me know the result.  Thanks!

Comment: @ParasGupta  I've further fine-tuned the code with newly added `MonthBegin` to pass a parameter `n=0` to ensure when the base date is on the 1st day of a month, it would not be rolled back to previous month.  Please try with the latest code.

Comment: @ParasGupta  Simplified the codes a bit with the use of `QuarterEnd` instead of `BQuarterEnd` and passing parameter `n=0` to  `QuarterEnd`.   Hopefully, this should be the finalized version.

Comment: Thanks. I was also messing with `QuarterEnd` using your clues. 
This one works perfectly. Great !!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a custom function. Maybe something like:

```
def custom_quarter_end(date, holidays=[]):
    holidays = [pd.Timestamp(h) for h in holidays]
    end = pd.Timestamp(date)+pd.tseries.offsets.BQuarterEnd()
    while end in holidays:
        end = end - pd.tseries.offsets.BDay()
    return end

>>> custom_quarter_end("2020-11-20", ["2020-12-30", "2020-12-31"])
Timestamp('2020-12-29 00:00:00')
```